# Accu-chek bluetooth connection - identification

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to connect a Roche Accu-chek device in flutter.

I plan a list where user can see all discovered devices, but only Accu-chek devices.

How can I detect that discovered device is an Accu-chek or not?
I see the device's service UUID: 0000**1808**-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb where **1808** meaning it is a Glucose type.

I think it is not clearly identified that it is an Accu-chek. Or am I wrong?

There is a manufacturer data as well, but I can not interpret it: {368: [215, 33, 0, 1, 0, 1]}. Maybe the answer is in this manufacturer data?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

**!!!UPDATE!!!**

Okay, I found that 368 is a company id, and it means Roche Diabetes Care AG.

But what in it int array? Can you explain me someone?

Comment: You are right, the glucose service you found does not identify the device, it is a standardised service UUID that can be used by everyone. You could filter for the glucose service and then again for the company id, but the manufacturer data can be whatever roche wanted it to be. Device Name, version, actual measurement data, ... You won't have much luck without a documentation

Comment: And unfortunately I can't find any documentation anywhere :( Is it also possible that different Roche products have different service features? E.g.: I can't find 1808 service on all devices

Comment: A manufacturer is not required to use any standard services. They can also develop their own BLE protocol for different scenarios. Using standardised profiles only helps to be compatible to each other.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can analyse in this way

1. If the device has a company id 368
2. If that device support the glucose service 1808

If both the conditions are satisfied, that's your identification

Answer (score -2):

Service
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb : Device Information

Has characteristics:

00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb : Serial Number

bytearray(b'9731264????')

39 37 33 31 32 36 34 ?? ?? ?? ??

00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb : Manufacturer Name

bytearray(b'Roche')

52 6f 63 68 65

00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb : Model Number

bytearray(b'973')

39 37 33

00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb : System ID

bytearray(b'\xdd\xd7\xdd\x05\x00\x19`\x00')

dd d7 dd 05 00 19 60 00

By reading the "Manufacturer Name" and "Serial Number" characteristics from the device, you can determine the model and type of ACCU-Chek device.
For example, serial numbers 6892* or "Model Number" 689 is Accu-Chek Performa, 973 is Accu-Chek Instant, 929 is Accu-Chek Guide.
You need to search the Internet for a list of correspondences or ask the manufacturer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).